# How to get a variable in an inner for loop in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello i am trying to parse an xml using XSLT

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <posts>
      <row Id="1" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="13" CreationDate="2010-09-13T19:16:26.763" Score="45" ViewCount="8799" Body="&lt;p&gt;This is a common question by those who have just rooted their phones.  What apps, ROMs, benefits, etc. do I get from rooting?  What should I be doing now?&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="10" LastEditorUserId="267" LastEditorDisplayName="" LastEditDate="2011-01-25T16:00:21.373" LastActivityDate="2011-08-02T14:44:12.740" CommunityOwnedDate="2011-01-25T08:44:10.820" Title="I've rooted my phone. Now what?" Tags="&lt;rooting&gt;" AnswerCount="8" CommentCount="5" FavoriteCount="31" />
      <row Id="2" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="4" CreationDate="2010-09-13T19:17:17.917" Score="10" ViewCount="619" Body="&lt;p&gt;I have a Google Nexus One with Android 2.2. I didn't like the default SMS-application so I installed Handcent-SMS. Now when I get an SMS, I get notified twice. How can I fix this?&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="7" LastEditorUserId="7" LastEditorDisplayName="" LastEditDate="2010-09-13T19:25:52.433" LastActivityDate="2010-09-13T19:25:52.433" Title="I installed another SMS application, now I get notified twice" Tags="&lt;2.2-froyo&gt;&lt;sms&gt;&lt;handcent-sms&gt;&lt;applications&gt;&lt;notifications&gt;" AnswerCount="3" FavoriteCount="2" />
      <row Id="4" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="2" CreationDate="2010-09-13T19:19:23.200" Score="16" ViewCount="" Body="&lt;p&gt;You can turn off notification in your stock Messaging application by going into the settings dialog  (Menu button -&gt; Settings) and unchecking Notifications&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="21" LastActivityDate="2010-09-13T19:19:23.200" CommentCount="1" />
      <row Id="5" PostTypeId="1" CreationDate="2010-09-13T19:19:35.360" Score="5" ViewCount="234" Body="&lt;p&gt;I have a Motorola DROID v1 that is running Froyo (2.2).  I've noticed that if my device sleeps for a while, when I wake it up it will not attempt to connect to the wireless AP in my home.  When I go to the wireless settings section, I see a note next to the AP entry that says 'disabled'.  If I click the entry and select 'connect', it connects right away.  It will remain connected until the next longish sleep, when it is again marked as disabled.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Is there any way to prevent this AP entry from being marked as disabled?&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="9" LastActivityDate="2011-09-05T03:43:01.573" Title="Moto Droid v1 disabling primary Wireless AP" Tags="&lt;2.2-froyo&gt;" AnswerCount="1" CommentCount="7" FavoriteCount="1" />
      <row Id="6" PostTypeId="1" CreationDate="2010-09-13T19:20:47.643" Score="2" ViewCount="67" Body="&lt;p&gt;Google recently intoduced a new mechanism for developers to protect their applications from piracy - the License Verification Library.  I've been looking at incorporating this into my apps (in fact I have it working) but I'm concerned that it will adversely affect the user experience.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Has anybody had problems using apps that incorporate the licensing check?  Does it cause problems when you don't have Internet connectivity in order to do the validation?  Are there any other annoyances from an end-user perspective?&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="19" LastActivityDate="2010-10-13T22:41:58.303" Title="Experiences with Google's new licensing service for apps?" Tags="&lt;market&gt;" AnswerCount="1" />
      <row Id="7" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="2" CreationDate="2010-09-13T19:20:52.027" Score="2" ViewCount="" Body="&lt;p&gt;Open the default messaging application, click the menu button and then Settings. Scroll down and disable &lt;strong&gt;Notifications&lt;/strong&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="27" LastActivityDate="2010-09-13T19:20:52.027" />
```

i use this to parse the xml

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="posts/row">
                <xsl:if test="@PostTypeId = 2">

                <xsl:variable name="parent" select="@ParentId"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="/posts/row">
                <xsl:if test="@PostTypeId = 1">
                 <xsl:variable name="patentVariable" select="$parent"/>
                               <xsl:if test="@ParentId = $patentVariable">
                    <field name ="$parentid"><xsl:value-of select="@Title" /></field>
                               </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>   
                </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i cannot print the parent id inside the for loop can any one tell me how to do this?

Expected output

```
<field name="1">I've rooted my phone. Now what?</field>
```

Comment: Hello! Would it be possible to show your expected output in this case? Thanks!

Comment: There is two types one is PostTypeId =1 which has the title attribute and second one is PostTypeId =2 which has the parentId which points to the PostType=1 i need to get the title for the postTypeId=2

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a very basic feature of XPath. Your XSLT shows that you do not seem to know about [XPath predicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) (i.e. filter expressions in square brackets).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="posts/row[@PostTypeId = 2]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row[@PostTypeId = 2]">
    <xsl:variable name="parent" select="@ParentId" />
    <field name="{$parent}">
      <xsl:value-of select="../row[@Id = $parent]/@Title" />
    </field>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you see, there is no need for things like `<xsl:if test="@PostTypeId = 2">`. I'd recommend reading into the basics of XPath.

Also note that you should avoid `<xsl:for-each>`. It's much less helpful than you think. Use `<xsl:apply-templates>` instead, like I show above.